# Add another row of form (django) with function on click

Tags: python, django

i'm doing a Django app. 
i have this form

```
class tipoAtribute(forms.Form):
 nombreAtribute = forms.CharField(max_length = 25)
 CHOICES = (
    ('VARCHAR', 'Categorico'),
    ('FLOAT', 'NUMERICO'))
 tipoAtribute = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = CHOICES, required=True, widget=forms.Select())
```

and i show this on a table in the HTML, like this:

```
<table id="atributesTable">
<tr>
    <td>
        {{ form.nombreAtribute }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ form.tipoAtribute }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

i made this Script to add another row in the table with the form inside.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("atributesTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

  cell1.innerHTML = "{{ form.nombreAtribute }}";
  cell2.innerHTML = "{{ form.tipoAtribute }}";
  }
```

but this simple doesn't work and i think is because im not showing appropriately the form in the variable cell1 or cell2. 
but i don't know how to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

The text replacement of `{{ form.nombreAtribute }}` might include quotes, which will make this script have syntax errors. View the page source in your browser to see the result of the template replacement. You can have Django escape the quotes by running the value through the [`addslashes` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#addslashes).

```
cell1.innerHTML = "{{ form.nombreAtribute | addslashes }}";
```

This may or may not be part of your problem.